# If/Else Statements Linux, Vi , Simple Scripts

Tags: linux, shell-script, vi

First I have tried finding answers to my questions and it's really difficult for a newbie to phrase his questions in a way that yields online results with answers relevant to the situation at hand.

That being said.

I am trying to write a simple program that prompts for what text you want to repeat (and how many times you'd like to repeat it. I have it working but for one of the variables (of how many times to repeat) if one inputs text instead of numbers, it will fail.
So how do I add an If/Else statement that won't break the script?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please input text you wish to print."
read text
echo "Please input number of times you wish to print text."
read number
if for i in `seq $number`;
do
    echo "$text"
else echo "Try again with valid input.";
done
```

---

This script works perfectly however.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Please input text you wish to print."
    read text
echo "Please input number of times you wish to print text."
    read number
for i in `seq $number`;
do
    echo "$text";
done
```

Comment: Please reformat your question and test the example you provide. There is markdown editing help under the question mark in the upper-right corner of the editing box

Comment: This site uses the [markdown formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1):

To test if your variable is a number, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806906/how-do-i-test-if-a-variable-is-a-number-in-bash#3951175).

Your `if` statement has no condition... The proper syntax is:

```
if [ some_condition ]
then
    # the code to execute if true (your `for` loop)
else 
    # the code to execute if false (optional)
fi  # "if" backwards
```